# Mapping from .vimrc does not apply

Tags: vim, vimrc, nnoremap

In my vimrc, I mapped `nnoremap <tab> >>` and `nnoremap <s-tab> <<`. The second mapping works fine, the first one however seems to be forgotten. If I map it manually when in Vim, it works though.

Any ideas about what's happening?

Answer (score 4):

The .vimrc file is loaded before plugins are loaded so it is possible that a plugin is overwriting your mapping.

You can find out what the mapping was set to and where it was set by issuing the [:verbose](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:verbose) command. For example (using [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)):

```
:verbose map <tab>
s  <Tab>       * <Esc>:call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim
x  <Tab>       * :call UltiSnips#SaveLastVisualSelection()<CR>gvs
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim
```

If you need to override the default set by a particular plugin, you could do so by adding your mapping to `.vim/after/plugin/<plugin name>.vim` (see [:h after-directory](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory)).